# Kubernetes/GKE Multi-tenant ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I see that its [recommended](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/best-practices/enterprise-multitenancy#load-balancing) to have single Ingress per cluster, when Implementing Multi-tenancy for Kubernetes Cluster.
That way,
`service1` of `tenanta` can have an endpoint such as `service1.tetanta.example.com`

The question I have is, how is this implemented in a multi-tenant scenario?

Considering Ingress is a single kubernetes object, what would the life cycle of Ingress object look like?

Who creates Ingress? (Supposed to be Platform team, if shared) and
How can tenants register their services with Ingress?

Any samples to explain this scenario are highly appreciated

Comment: Have you considered to use the newer Gateway API instead of Ingress? I think it is easier in your use case. See https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/gateway-api

Answer (score 0):

A multi-tenant cluster is shared by various clients and responsibilities which are alluded to as "occupants". To prevent a compromised or malicious tenant from causing harm to the cluster and other tenants, operators of multi-tenant clusters must separate tenants from one another. Additionally, tenants must be fairly allocated cluster resources.

As per this [doc](https://www.nginx.com/blog/enabling-multi-tenancy-namespace-isolation-in-kubernetes-with-nginx/#Implementing-Restricted-Self-Service) written by Amir Rawdat:

> NGINX Ingress Controller supports multi-tenancy models, but there are
> two main patterns. The foundation specialist co-op design ordinarily
> incorporates various NGINX Entrance Regulator organizations with
> actual disengagement, while the venture design normally utilizes a
> common NGINX Entrance Regulator sending with namespace separation. In
> this part we investigate the endeavor design top to bottom; Check out
> our documentation for more details on how to run multiple NGINX
> Ingress Controllers.
>
> NGINX Ingress Controller supports both the standard Kubernetes Ingress
> resource and custom NGINX Ingress resources, which enable both more
> sophisticated traffic management and delegation of control over
> configuration to multiple teams. The custom resources are
> VirtualServer, VirtualServerRoute, GlobalConfiguration,
> TransportServer, and Policy.
>
> When implementing multi-tenancy in your Kubernetes cluster, you have
> two options: full self service and restricted self-service.

Refer to this  [blog 1](https://gcloud.devoteam.com/blog/deploying-multi-tenant-kubernetes-deployments-in-a-vpc-native-cluster-with-spinnaker-on-gke/) authored by Devoteam and [blog 2](https://blog.mikesir87.io/2022/01/making-kubernetes-multi-tenant/)  written by Michael for more information about creating and usage of a multi-tenant deployment in kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

Gateway is helpful as @Jonas suggested in his comments

Gateway API offers a modular approach to solve this problem

https://medium.com/google-cloud/gateway-gke-multi-tenancy-creating-one-per-cluster-shared-load-balancer-for-multi-tenant-gke-3465a8ae882a